# Angular typescript test with jest and spectator cover component methods in sonarqube

Tags: angular, sonarqube, code-coverage, istanbul, ts-jest

I am using following for my angular project
Angular CLI: 10.2.3

Node: 12.22.1

I have following dependencies (for testing)

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1002.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.2",
    "@ngneat/spectator": "^5.13.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0-next.1",
    "jest": "^27.0.5",
    "jest-mock-extended": "^1.0.16",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^9.0.4",
    "ngx-deploy-npm": "^1.2.2",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  }
```

I want to understand how to improve the coverage of my test so sonarqube report is showing better coverage.

I have one component as below. I have added "istanbul ignore next" comment for the constructor otherwise the coverage report shows that I am not covering those line of codes. I do not want to test private constructor, so using the above comment.

```
// Private class used by the component. do not want to test it.  
export class Summary {

  /* istanbul ignore next */
  constructor(
    public vDate: Date,
    public bookName: string,
    .
    .
  ) {
    }
}

export class SummaryComponent implements OnInit {

    ngOnInit(): void {
    .
    .
    }
    
    handleUserSelection(selection) {
        console.log("Handle User Selection");
        console.log("Selection: " + selection.selectedDateTo.year);
        console.log("Selection: " + selection.selectedDateFrom.month);
        if (selection.selectedDateTo instanceof Date && selection.selectedDateTo.getTime()) {
          this.currentDateTo = this.util.formatCalendarDateToDateStr(selection.selectedDateTo);     
        } else {
          this.currentDateTo = this.util.formatCalendarDateToDateStr(new Date(selection.selectedDateTo.year,selection.selectedDateTo.month - 1,selection.selectedDateTo.day));
        }
        if (selection.selectedDateFrom instanceof Date && selection.selectedDateFrom.getTime()) {
          this.currentDateFrom = this.util.formatCalendarDateToDateStr(selection.selectedDateFrom);
        } else {
          this.currentDateFrom = this.util.formatCalendarDateToDateStr(new Date(selection.selectedDateFrom.year,selection.selectedDateFrom.month - 1,selection.selectedDateFrom.day));
        }

        console.log(selection);
        .
        .
        
    }
}
```

Basically, I have a method in a component. My test file looks like this:

```
describe('SummaryComponent', () => {

  let spectator: Spectator<SummaryComponent>;
  const createComponent = createComponentFactory({
    component: SummaryComponent,
    declarations: [],
    imports: [HttpClientTestingModule,
              MatSnackBarModule,
              RouterTestingModule
             ],
    providers: [
      { provide: MatDialog, useClass: MatDialogMock },
    ],
    schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
    mocks: [BasicAuthService,            
            SummaryDataService,            
           ],
    detectChanges: false
  });
  
  beforeEach(()=> {
    spectator= createComponent();    
  });
  
  it('should handle user selection', () => {    
    jest.spyOn(spectator.component, 'handleUserSelection').mockReturnValue(null);
    spectator.component.handleUserSelection(selection);
    expect(spectator.component.handleUserSelection).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

});
```

In my coverage, it shows the method is not covered at all.
[image]

How can I improve test, so that the method is covered?

**UPDATE:**

I tried to mock implement the function as below:

```
it('should handle user selection', () => {    
    jest.spyOn(spectator.component, 'handleUserSelection').mockImplementation(() => {
      
      let jSelection: any = {
        selectedDateFrom: {year: 2020, month: 5, day: 29},
        selectedDateTo: {year: 2020, month: 6, day: 30},        
      };

      console.log("Handle User Selection");
      console.log("Selection: " + jSelection.selectedDateTo.year);
      console.log("Selection: " + jSelection.selectedDateFrom.month);

      if (jSelection.selectedDateTo instanceof Date && jSelection.selectedDateTo.getTime()) {
        spectator.component.currentDateTo = spectator.component.util.formatCalendarDateToDateStr(jSelection.selectedDateTo);     
      } else {
        spectator.component.currentDateTo = spectator.component.util.formatCalendarDateToDateStr(new Date(jSelection.selectedDateTo.year,jSelection.selectedDateTo.month - 1,jSelection.selectedDateTo.day));
      }
      if (jSelection.selectedDateFrom instanceof Date && jSelection.selectedDateFrom.getTime()) {
        spectator.component.currentDateFrom = spectator.component.util.formatCalendarDateToDateStr(jSelection.selectedDateFrom);
      } else {
        spectator.component.currentDateFrom = spectator.component.util.formatCalendarDateToDateStr(new Date(jSelection.selectedDateFrom.year,jSelection.selectedDateFrom.month - 1,jSelection.selectedDateFrom.day));
      }

      console.log("Handle user selection Done!");

    });
    
    spectator.component.handleUserSelection(selection);
    expect(spectator.component.handleUserSelection).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Still the coverage shows the same i.e. the function is not covered at all?

what should I do to have the method covered?

Answer (score 1):

I meant this to be a comment, but sadly I don't have enough reputation.

Looking at your code snippet, I have a doubt that why you're mocking the exact method you are trying to test? should not we just mock the functions that your `handleUserSelection` needs to call. I believe that this way, your actual code of `handleUserSelection` never even gets executed during unit test, because it always returns the mocked implementation instead of actual function call.

My suggestion would be to try and call the `handleUserSelection` method without `jest.spyOn` and mock methods like `spectator.component.util.formatCalendarDateToDateStr`. After all, unit test should only focus on current block of code, and not the subsequent code which is getting called.